# Is it possible to convert a .vhd file to an Image through API in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to upload a .vhd file to Microsoft Azure through Azure CLI. The uploaded .vhd gets stored to an Azure container.

I can manually launch it by converting it into an Image in Azure's portal. But I want to do the same operation through its API. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

See the command "azure vm image create" for creating an image using CLI. (For PowerShell it would be the command Add-AzureVMImage.)

For further information see the integrated help as below:

```
azure help vm image create

info:    Executing command help
help:    Upload and register a VM image
help:
help:    Usage: vm image create [options] <name> [source-path]
help:
help:    Options:
help:      -h, --help                   output usage information
help:      -v, --verbose                use verbose output
help:      --json                       use json output
help:      -u, --blob-url <url>         the target image blob url
help:      -l, --location <name>        the location
help:      -a, --affinity-group <name>  the affinity group
help:      -o, --os <type>              the operating system [linux|windows]
help:      -p, --parallel <number>      the maximum number of parallel  uploads [96]
help:      -m, --md5-skip               skip MD5 hash computation
help:      -f, --force-overwrite        Force overwrite of prior uploads
help:      -e, --label <about>          the image label
help:      -d, --description <about>    the image description
help:      -b, --base-vhd <blob>        the base vhd blob url
help:      -k, --source-key <key>       the source storage key if source-path
help:                               is a Microsoft Azure private blob url
help:      -s, --subscription <id>      the subscription id
```